# Adapting ‘print’ call to Python 2.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.4

I tested the following code with an online Python 3.x compiler but want a similar one to work on my 2.4.3 compiler:

```
import sys, time

print('I am about to show you something _\b', end='')
sys.stdout.flush() # Make sure above string gets printed in time
time.sleep(2)
print('THIS!')
```

How can I make a similar code work for Python 2.4.3?

Comment: Did you try this code in Python 2.4?

Comment: print is not function until python 3

Comment: May I suggest if you are learning Python, you should upgrade to Python3. [Python2 will be at end-of-life soon](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/)

Comment: i have tried other versions of this code to try to make it work but it generates a syntax error.

Comment: Do you *really* need to keep using Python 2.4? That release is coming up on 12 years old, and has been unsupported for a very long time. It has security bugs that will not be fixed (they are fixed in newer releases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `print` statement with trailing comma to suppress the newline:

```
import time
import sys

print 'I am about to show you something _\b',
sys.stdout.flush() # Make sure above string gets printed in time
time.sleep(2)
print 'THIS!'
```

Alternatively, write to `sys.stdout` directly:

```
sys.stdout.write('I am about to show you something ')
sys.stdout.flush() # Make sure above string gets printed in time
time.sleep(2)
sys.stdout.write('THIS!')
```

This works in Python 2 and 3 alike.